# Padding Zeroes in Decimals Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am having some issues dealing with numeric columns and data stored in tables. The columns are of type Number(14,2). If there are any decimal digits in numbers (like 1234.65) then it works fine. But when the numbers like 1234.00 are stored the decimal zeroes are removed when stored in tables. Another case is when numbers like 1234.50 are stored it stores as 1234.5

This is causing issue when I am retrieving the values, it is not consistent when it is displayed on User screens. We are handling the decimal digits based on flag whether to display or not. When chosen to display the number wont align because of this mismatch stored in database. The UI would display like this.

```
      0

      0

14922.9

14922.9

14922.93
```

But I want it to look like this if I wanted to show values after decimal point -

```
    0.00

    0.00

14922.90

14922.90

14922.93
```

This can be fixed on UI side, but the problem is every application using this table has to fix on its own UI part. We have a SQL view which is reading this table.

So I was wondering if there a way to fix this from SQL side and can be handled in SQL view query.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could do this with some casting to strings and so on but the SQL side is the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the number format when select the values:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(number, '90.99')
  FROM DUAL;
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51075

Answer (score 0):

Let's cast first before using the string function to make sure we have correct numeric type.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,2)), '9999999999990.99') AS output
FROM dual;
```